# Element exceeding column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I tried to create a form and put a back button next to it. Now the problem I am facing is that parent column is `col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4` but a nested column into the mentioned column exceeds its limit and is moving out of `col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4`. I tried to figure it out but couldn't find a logical explanation to it. I am also posting code and images of the problem I am facing.

```html
@section('body')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            
            <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-11">
                <div class="col-lg-9"><h3>Edit Record</h3></div>
                
                <div class="col-lg-1 pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Back</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <form class="well">
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{$rec->title}}"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{$rec->body}}"><br>

                    <div class="col-lg-offset-5">
                        <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        </div>
            
    </div>

@endsection
```

`col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4`
[image: col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4]

This is how it is exceeding the limit

[image: col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4]

Please someone explain how and why is this happening?

Comment: can you add the html please? or codesnippet

Comment: @JoshAdams plz check out, I have posted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have columns nested directly under other columns, you have to use nested rows and columns must be the only elements under rows, so this:

```
<div class="row">
    <br>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">

        <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-11">
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

needs to become like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-11">
            [...]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, remember that when you create a new nested row/cols it will still be divided in twelve parts but the size will be that of the container element. In your case the `<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-11">` will be 11/12 of `<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">` so you have to adjust because 11+3 = 14

**Example:**

Not sure if this looks exactly how you want it to look but it's a working starting point... feel free to edit it however you need:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- size this "col" however you want it -->
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-8">
                    <h3>Edit Record</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Back</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-9">
                        <!-- you may want to put these two inputs in their own rows/columns too -->
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{$rec->title}}"><br>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{$rec->body}}"><br>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col">
                        <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if I take `<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-9">` the button still falls out of the container element i.e `<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">` Why is that?

Comment: As said, you also need to nest rows and columns the right way. Whenever you need a new set of columns it must be enclosed in a row. I don't know if you have corrected the code above but you have columns nested inside other columns and you can't do it.
Rows can only contain columns, columns can contain whatever you want (except for other columns as direct children), including other rows which in turn will contain other columns.

Comment: I've detailed my answer more, hope it helps.

Comment: I have upvoted you but am waiting for some other answers. If your answer is found to be correct will accept it as an answer.

Comment: I've added a working example to my reply above, feel free to use it as a starting point ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate the help.